# Center Storyboard Views in autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So basically, I have a `UITextView` that I want centered in my `UIView`.  Here's my view controller code below:

```
import UIKit

class OpeningScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topBarUIView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topViewTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let superViewWidth = view.frame.size.width
        let superViewHeight = view.frame.size.height

    //creating the top bar
        topBarUIView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: superViewWidth, height: superViewHeight * 0.1)
        topBarUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

    //adding text to the top bar
        topViewTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, superViewWidth, superViewHeight * 0.1)
        topViewTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        topViewTextView.text = "Hello World"
        topViewTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        topViewTextView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)        
    }    
}
```

I change the opacity of my background view to 50 % and the textView to a background color of blue, but when I run this, the blue background is well within the UIView, like 10 ish pixels on one side, and 20 on the other.  I'm not sure why.

I set it up in storyboard, and cnt-dragged it on, and then changed the properties of the views in viewDidAppear to override the storyboard.

Also I tried doing things like:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {       
    // Get the superview's layout
    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide

    // Pin the leading edge of myView to the margin's leading edge
    topBarUIView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).active = true

    // Pin the trailing edge of myView to the margin's trailing edge
    topBarUIView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true

    // Give myView a 1:2 aspect ratio
    topBarUIView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topBarUIView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0)
}
```

And got a weird error saying that the layout constraints were having a problem.

Would it be easier to set the view's height and width and starting point separately? If so how can I do something like this pseudocode:

```
topBar.startingPoint = (x,y)
topBar.height = this
topBar.width = this
```

etc.

Comment: Why are you not applying constraints in stroryboard??

Comment: I was asked to do it as programmatically as possible, and avoid storyboard as much as I could.

Comment: Kindly use autolayout or it will be a mess for you to handle.I don't know if its your project requirement to not use autolayout or somebody told you.If somebody told than i am telling you from experience its the wrong direction that you are following

Answer (score 1):

In a modern application you should never be setting `.frame` directly. Especially not in `viewDidAppear` -- your layout changes on rotate and in Slide Over or Split View multitasking whilst remaining visible.

The correct thing to do is always to use Auto Layout, and generally to apply all your Auto Layout constraints in Interface Builder, customizing by size class where necessary, and preview them there. Any misspecifications can be corrected much more easily that way. Excellent tutorials can be found at [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/):

- [Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 9 Part 1: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)
- [Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 9 Part 2: Constraints](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints)
- [Easier Auto Layout: Coding Constraints in iOS 9](https://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout)

Comment: Understood.  Here's the thing, this is just an iPhone app - and more or less an exercise in programmatically doing views with storyboards as just a prototype.  Maybe we're doing this as an exercise to show us how hard or dumb or whatever, the approach is, I'm not sure.  I was just wondering why the text field wasn't going to the frame I set it.  Did I set the frame incorrectly?  If I put the code in viewDidLoad, then storyboard will over write the code, hence it was in viewDidAppear.  But again, I'm not an expert, really just a new student, and just curious about this.

Comment: Your changes to the frame are overwritten by the next Auto Layout pass, which happens as soon as any view invalidates its contents or position. If you really really want to fight the framework, you can make visible frame changes in a ` viewDidLayoutSubviews()` override, or completely turn off Auto Layout.